# list and read the MAC addresses of available wifi networks without having to disconnect from the current network

Tags: blackberry

I want to list and read the MAC addresses of available wifi network in an app without having to disconnect from the current network I am connected to. is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are talking about BlackBerry Java applications, the short answer is you can't.  With respect to BB10 aps, sorry don't know.  I would search the BB10 forum for similar questions.

[BB10 Native Development forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/bd-p/Cascades)